# Optimal solution to Cartesian Product of two sets (computationally)

Tags: database-theory

Given two large sets (say 1 million items each), what is the fastest way to compare the values with each other.

This is a typical join problem, for which there are two standard solutions:

1. nested loop join
2. hash join

The nested loop is naive because it compares every value to every other value. This makes it slower than optimal. But it allows doing arbitrary comparison types like `>=`, in addition to just `=`.

The hash join is better because you can take one set, compute the hash for the value, then go through the second set and compute the hash to lookup if the element exists. But this only allows for comparison to be equality check `=`. It doesn't allow for `>=`, for example.

Wondering if there is a current optimal solution that allows for doing the Cartesian Product comparison without naively iterating through both sets, while also allowing for arbitrary comparison types like `>=`, `<`, etc.

**Update**

By optimal I mean anything better than comparing everything to everything else. At least more optimal than that. The hashing example is more optimal because it only has to scan both lists once (I think) rather than n x m times or however.

By "allowing for arbitrary comparison types like >=" I am referencing that, for example, hash joins can only be applied on equality comparison, since you are doing a hash to get an index in the build and probe tables; you can't do >=, <=, >, <, ! (not), etc. with a hash join (from my understanding). But you can with nested loops. So I am looking for the join operator being able to perform all of the comparison types, not just equality. By all we can just say range queries >=, <=, >, < and not queries !. I guess a hash join could handle ! as well probably.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve.  What do you mean by "compare the values with each other"?  What do you want the output/result of the operation to be?  Do you want to compute the join of the two lists?  And I still think you need to define what you mean by "optimal".  Better in what respect?  "More optimal" is a contradiction in terms; that's like saying "more pregnant".

Comment: Please don't use "stuff.  UPDATE: more stuff."  Instead, revise the question to read well from the start.  Don't just append to the end of your question.  Instead, revise and rewrite the question to be clear and read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.

Comment: Sort each list in $O(n \log n)$ time, then merge the sorted lists in $O(n)$ time.  (The usual list merge can be adapted easily to output only equal elements.)  This will handle predicates like $\le$, but such a predicate is liable to produce $\Omega(n^2)$ output, in which case there is no escaping that time complexity (the best you can hope for is to write out each item in $O(1)$).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Not sure exactly what you mean. I get the part "Sort each list in O(nlogn) time, then merge the sorted lists in O(n) time. (The usual list merge can be adapted easily to output only equal elements.)". Are you saying during the sort you will do the `<=` and it will end up being $Ω(n^2)$ anyways. I just keep wondering if a B+tree can somehow be used to prevent the $Ω(n^2)$ case.

Comment: I mean that if the predicate is $\le$ then it's very easy to wind up with a large fraction of all possible $n^2$ pairs in the output.  (This is still possible even if the predicate is $=$: It could be that every single item in each set is the same value, say 42, in which case $=$ will produce all $n^2$ pairs.  I'm assuming here that you really meant "multiset" -- if you genuinely meant "set" (i.e., that an item can appear at most once in each side), then the $=$ predicate is "safe" -- it can only produce $O(n)$ output items.)

Comment: Yeah you're right it is multiset. Ok I am following now, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)